# How Sign a PDF File using a Ceritificate PKCS11, SmartCard-eToken and itextsharp in .NET?

Tags: itext, digital-signature, x509certificate, smartcard, pkcs#11

Sorry, but I don't speak english, and I will do my best.

I tried to sign a PDF document with a digital certificate from PKCS # 11 type in C #. NET 4.0. As you know such a certificate requires a private key, in my case is stored on an Aladdin eToken, and then make a signature using itextsharp.

I tried with CAPICOM, System.Security.Cryptography, BouncyCastle, Chilkat, Net.Pkcs11, etc. But no works.

PdfSignatureAppearance has the method SetCrypto(key, cert, ..., ...) , where the first parameter is the key of the certificate and the second parameter is the same certificate, but I can't get the private key of the eToken. Hey read and think this is impossible.

I'm using C # native, using cryptography. NET in a few lines of code:

```
X509Certificate2 x509 = (Certificate from X509Certificate2Collection);
CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters(1",eToken Base Cryptographic Provider", "Default")
cspParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams))
{
byte[] signature = rsa.SignData(x509.RawData, "SHA1");
//I don't know how join it with itextsharp
rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
rsa.Clear();
}
```

I think I can use the method SignData(), but I'm a little confused. How I can relate itextsharp.

I found much documentation but nothing specific, such as java applets do not work because I have Windows 7 64 bits, and codes. NET does not work. I would, if possible, use the same core. NET or free libraries with support for Windows 7 64 bits. Someone did a real solution?

Also I would like to know how to delete the eToken PIN cache since it only asks me for the password once and then stays in memory.

Please I need your help.

Thank you.

Comment: As you tried so many, I guess you also tried our SecureBlackbox, haven't you? It provides PKCS#11 support for .NET, including PDF signing using certificates stored on crypto devices.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this great framework to work with tokens: pkcs11.net
found in here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pkcs11net/

The thing is:
with the rsa private key and certificate you got from the token, you it with use IText to sign. With the key, is the plain signing you are shown in IText's web site.

You see, `pdf signing` is different from `pkcs7 signing`, and that is different from `xml signing`.

Post a comment if you need more info

Comment: Just a note - most PKCS#11 devices won't give you the private key for security reasons.